# R: Superimposing Two Graphs Together

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am using the R programming language. Using the following link (https://bio304-class.github.io/bio304-book/introduction-to-ggplot2.html) , I made these two plots for the iris dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

data(iris)

#graph1

setosa.only <- subset(iris, Species == "setosa")

setosa.sepals <- ggplot(setosa.only, 
                        mapping = aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width))

graph1 = setosa.sepals  + geom_point() + sepal.labels

#graph2

graph2 = setosa.sepals + 
  geom_density2d() + 
  sepal.labels + labs(subtitle = "I. setosa data only")

cowplot::plot_grid(graph1, graph2, labels = "AUTO")
```

[image]

My question: is it possible to combine both of these graphs together into 1 single plot?
So that it looks something like this? (I tried to draw this by hand):

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `geom_density2d()` after `geom_point()` :

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(setosa.only, 
       mapping = aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_density2d()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! After 10 minutes, I will be able to "accept" your answer!